# Eclipse Java Comments auto alignment plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-formatting

Is there any eclipse plugin which aligns the inline comments - comments present on the line of code but not the whole line comment.

For example consider if the code is as follows:

```
//whole line comment 
class Class1
{
    void method1()
    {
        //whole line comment
        int linePointer; //inline comment
        BufferredReader br = new BufferredReader(); //inline comment
        File f = new File(); //inline comment
    }
}
```

They it should be formatted as follows:

```
//whole line comment 
class Class1
{
    void method1()
    {
        //whole line comment
        int linePointer;                            //inline comment
        BufferredReader br = new BufferredReader(); //inline comment
        File f = new File();                        //inline comment
    }
}
```

Is there any way to imitate this by tweaking eclipse java code editor settings?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way doing this in Eclipse. So I wrote a Perl script.
https://github.com/ttt43ttt/handy-perl/blob/master/align_inline_comments.pl

```
perl align_inline_comments.pl filepath.java 120
```

120 is the left-padding of inline comments (default value is 80).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution (workaround)

an Ahk implementation (as workaround -- I didnt find a way to do it in Eclipse)::

to use, just

1. make sure your right most comment is placed in a good position (other comments will align to this right most one)
2. run ahk
3. select your code to reformat
4. press the hotkey `^+g (ctrl + shift + g)`
5. the reformatted code will be pasted

```
/* 
@logic,to_use::
1. make sure your right most comment is placed in a good position <strike> 1. use eclipse to reformat the comments `//`
1. scan through all lines to see which `//` is the right most 
- ignore the lines with not code on the right
1. locate all the `//` & add enough space to align with the right most `//`
*/
alignJavaComment(content_CodeToAlign) {
  ; >> 1. scan through all lines to see which `//` is the right most 
  ;~ stdout := FileOpen("*", "w")
  arr_ind_CommentDelimiter := []
  ; https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm
  Loop, parse, content_CodeToAlign, `n, `r 
  {
    line_curr := A_LoopField
    ; ;V1; ind_CommentDelimiter := RegExMatch(line_curr, "//") ; starts from 1 not 0 ; Position 1 is the first character. ; 0 means not found
    ; ;V1; arr_ind_CommentDelimiter.Push(ind_CommentDelimiter)
    ind_CommentDelimiter := RegExMatch(line_curr, "//")
    ; determine if the comment is behind code, or the comment is the whole line 
    ; ;M*; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word
    ; ;M*; can do sth like `^(?!\s*//)(.*)(//)`, but nah .. 
    ; if the comment is the whole line -> dont align it -- push index 0
    ; @explain-minor: if the comment is the whole line -- the preceding part P1 is all white space -- RegExMatch cant find "^\s*$" & return 0
    line_curr_P1 := SubStr(line_curr, 1, ind_CommentDelimiter - 1)
    ind_det_ItsAllWhiteSpace := RegExMatch(line_curr_P1, "^\s*$")
    ;~ stdout.WriteLine("line_curr_P1: " . line_curr_P1)
    ;~ stdout.WriteLine("ind_det_ItsAllWhiteSpace: " . ind_det_ItsAllWhiteSpace)
    ;~ stdout.WriteLine("ind_CommentDelimiter: " . ind_CommentDelimiter)
    if (ind_det_ItsAllWhiteSpace != 0) {
      arr_ind_CommentDelimiter.Push(0)
    } 
    ; if the comment is behind code -> align it -- push corresponding index
    ; if there is no comment in this code -> dont align it -- push index 0
    else {
      arr_ind_CommentDelimiter.Push(ind_CommentDelimiter)
    }
  }
  ; https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Math.htm#Max
  ind_RightMostCommentDelimiter := Max(arr_ind_CommentDelimiter*)
  ;~ stdout.WriteLine(ind_RightMostCommentDelimiter)
  
  ; >> 1. locate all the `//` & add enough space to align with the right most `//`
  content_Aligned := ""
  Loop, parse, content_CodeToAlign, `n, `r 
  {
    line_curr := A_LoopField
    ind_line_curr := A_Index
    ;~ stdout.WriteLine(ind_line_curr) ; starts from 1 not 0
    ind_CommentDelimiter_curr := arr_ind_CommentDelimiter[ind_line_curr] ; starts from 1 not 0 ; Ahk array start from 1 not 0 (.... how i have no strong impression..)
    ;~ stdout.WriteLine(ind_CommentDelimiter_curr)
    if (ind_CommentDelimiter_curr == 0) {
      content_Aligned .= line_curr . "`n"
    } else {
      ind_DiffNumOfSpaces := ind_RightMostCommentDelimiter - ind_CommentDelimiter_curr
      ; https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/102416-insert-character-into-a-string-at-a-specific-position/
      line_curr_P1 := SubStr(line_curr, 1, ind_CommentDelimiter_curr - 1)
      line_curr_P2 := SubStr(line_curr, ind_CommentDelimiter_curr)
      ;~ stdout.WriteLine(ind_line_curr . ": " . line_curr_P1 . line_curr_P2 . " -- " . ind_DiffNumOfSpaces)
      str_Spaces := "" ; need to reset in each Loop ...
      Loop, %ind_DiffNumOfSpaces% 
      {
        str_Spaces .= " "
      }
      content_Aligned .= line_curr_P1 . str_Spaces . line_curr_P2 . "`n"
    }
  }
  
  return content_Aligned
}

; ;testing; content_Test := ""
; ;testing; . "  public static void main(String[] args) {" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "    Channel channel; // = ...;" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "    // Does not block" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "    ChannelFuture future = channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(""192.168.0.1"", 25)); // statement A" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "    future.addListener(" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                       new ChannelFutureListener()" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                       {" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                         @Override" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                         public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {  // statement A" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                           if (future.isSuccess()) {" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                             ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(""Hello"", Charset.defaultCharset());" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                             ChannelFuture wf = future.channel()  // statement A" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                                                      .writeAndFlush(buffer);" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                             // ...." . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                           } else {  // statement A" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                             Throwable cause = future.cause();" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                             cause.printStackTrace();  // statement A" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                           }" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                         }" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "                       });" . "`n"
; ;testing; . "  }" . "`n"
; ;testing; 
; ;testing; content_Aligned := alignJavaComment(content_Test)
; ;testing; stdout := FileOpen("*", "w")
; ;testing; stdout.WriteLine(content_Aligned)


^+g::
Clipboard := ""
SendInput, ^c
ClipWait, 0.3

content_Aligned := alignJavaComment(Clipboard)
Clipboard := content_Aligned

SendInput, ^v
return
```